# Is it possible to hook a non-configurable property like window.location.hostname, in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, window, overriding, hook, defineproperty

I would like to know if there is a way to hook a non-configurable property, like `window.location.hostname`.

By this, I mean if it's possible to get an event/do something when a non-configurable property is accessed?

For example, it is currently possible to be notified and to do something when the `window.navigator.userAgent` property is called:

```
(function() {
    var userAgent = window.navigator.userAgent;
    Object.defineProperty(window.navigator, "userAgent", {
        get: function() {
            console.log("hello from useragent");
            return userAgent;
        }
    });
})();
```

However, in my case, I need to do the same thing when the `window.location.hostname` property is accessed, but I can't find anything that allows me to do this.

Thank you very much for your help,

**Bests!**

Answer (score 0):

You can save the domain in a global variable and then take advantage of your existing ***onload*** event to check each time for change, like this...

```
var Saved_Domain=''; // global
```

//----------------------------

```
window.addEventListener('load',function(){

 
 if((Saved_Domain!=='')&&(window.location.hostname!==Saved_Domain)){

  // The domain changed so do something here

  Saved_Domain=window.location.hostname; // save it again  

 }

     
 // other after-load tasks continue running here
     
  

},false);
```

Actually scratch that...

If *window.location.hostname* has changed then a new document has loaded into the window... in which case you can't keep track of a domain change from the same document!

Or are you in control of the window/frame but haven't mentioned it?

Comment: In fact, I just want to hook the `window.location.hostname` in order to be notified when this property is used. For example, if there is a snippet code that is trying to compare the `window.location.hostname` with a hard-coded value, I would like to be able to modify the result of the `window.location.hostname` property. In other words, I would like to be able to override the property. I know that's possible with some properties, but idk how to do that (and if it's possible) with non-configurable properties.